# how to write software description for patent request

Tags: description, request

OK i finally finished my software, now i want to write a patent request,
my software is like a big network that contains many internal softwares.
the problem is that the internal   software is made for specific company, but  the big software which is the network it can be used in every company,i just need to edit the internal software and make other depend what the other company needs..
the question is, when i write my software description do i describe the software 
that its for specific company, or i describe it as a global one?
and do i talk about the conceptual model as well? or maybe i should just find 
someone else to do this in my place? im not sure. any advice would be a big help! ty

Comment: @EricShain Please stop answering questions in comments. Your initial comments elicited replies in kind and the entire issue was resolved... in comments — and yet the question remains unanswered. Please stop using this site in this manner. This is not a discussion forum. thank you.

Comment: @RobertCartaino My "answer" was essentially saying there is no way to answer the question. My response to the questioner's comments was to iterate that we can't answer this question. I don't believe answering questions with "we can't answer the question" is appropriate. That should be part of your response to guide searcher who come after.

Comment: @EricShain The ultimate purpose of this site is to help future users who may run into this issue. Responses such as *"what you are asking is not possible"* or *"doing this yourself is not appropriate; you need a lawyer "* are perfectly appropriate if that is the correct response to the question... assuming you can so authoritatively.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I really do believe I understand the purpose of this site. Recently I've been the most active user answering questions.

Comment: @EricShain Fair enough; I am also talking over your shoulder to anyone else looking on who might less familiar with the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering recent court cases [(most prominently Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International)), it is difficult to draft an application to get a patent on software innovations. A more narrow and specific question on the topic might get a good answer here, but this very general question is not really answerable. I recommend you get professional help.